# Jquery on change not working after post

Tags: jquery, jquery-post

I'm having a problem using .on() method after post.
I have 3 dropdowns each one populated after first one changed.
When i change first dropdown, the other ones are repopulated based on mysql database tables.
The problem is the separated function for second dropdown doesn't work separately.
Here's the html:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="inputIlha">Ilha</label><select name="ilha" class="form-control" id="inputIlha">
            <option value="1">Santa Maria</option>
            <option value="2">São Miguel</option>
            <option value="3">Terceira</option>
            <option value="4">Graciosa</option>
            <option value="5">São Jorge</option>
            <option value="6">Pico</option>
            <option value="7">Faial</option>
            <option value="8">Flores</option>
            <option value="9">Corvo</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="inputConcelho">Concelho</label>
        <select name="concelho" class="form-control" id="inputConcelho">
            <option value="0"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="inputFreguesia">Freguesia</label>
        <select name="freguesia" class="form-control" id="inputFreguesia">
            <option value="0"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And jquery function that repopulates all the dropdowns succesfully:

```
$("#inputIlha").on("change", function() {
    var inputIlha = document.getElementById("inputIlha").value;
    $.post(config.base + "xxxx/xxxxxx/xxx01", { ilha: inputIlha }, function(result) {
        $( "#inputConcelho" ).replaceWith(result );
        var inputConcelho = document.getElementById("inputConcelho").value;
            $.post(config.base + "xxxx/xxxxxx/xxx02", { concelho: inputConcelho }, function(result) {
                $( "#inputFreguesia" ).replaceWith(result);
            });
        //$( "#inputFreguesia" ).html('<option value="0"></option>');
        }
    );
});
```

This function repopulates the second (#inputConcelho) and third (#inputFreguesia) dropdown correctly. #inputFreguesia is repopulated successfully based on #inputConcelho.

The problem is when i want to change the #inputConcelho. The next function won't work.

```
$("#inputConcelho").on("change", function() {
alert("inputConcelho changed");
    var inputConcelho = document.getElementById("inputConcelho").value;
    $.post(config.base + "xxxx/xxxxxx/xxx02", { concelho: inputConcelho }, function(result) {
        $( "#inputFreguesia" ).replaceWith(result );
    });
});
```

I tried adding alert to see if any response but not success. I even tried this simply function:

```
$("#inputConcelho").click(function() {
    alert("inputConcelho changed");
});
```

Everytime i change first dropdown (#inputIlha) the dropdowns are all repopulated.
But when i change just the second dropwdown (#inputConcelho), i get not alert or anything.
Any idea what might be the problem? I even tried adding a class to second dropdown, and call it with that class without success. Hope i made myself clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are replacing the second select element, the handlers added to those elements are lost.

It is the same as [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements).

So you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) here.

```
$("#inputConcelho").parent().on("change", '#inputConcelho', function () {
    alert("inputConcelho changed");
    var inputConcelho = document.getElementById("inputConcelho").value;
    $.post(config.base + "xxxx/xxxxxx/xxx02", {
        concelho: inputConcelho
    }, function (result) {
        $("#inputFreguesia").replaceWith(result);
    });
});
```

Instead of binding the handler to `#inputConcelho`, bind it to that element's parent

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. Would be a better practice to use .html() instead of replaceWith like Pierre-Chanel answered?

Comment: @JonnyDevv yes... if you have control over the script that will be better

Answer (score 2):

I think you shouldn't use `.replaceWith()` function, because it replace all the element (remove it from the DOM). Use better `.html(result)` and change the result send by your server in order to have only `<option>` elements.